# How fix error in Django templates/base.py?

Tags: python, django

I am trying to install Geonode 2.8 on Ubuntu 16.04 and I get an error from Django. I have no idea how to solve problem in the internal files of Django.

```
$ sudo django-admin startproject --template=https://github.com/GeoNode/geonode/archive/2.8.x.zip -e py,rst,json,yml my_geonode6


Traceback (most recent call last):

File "/usr/local/bin/django-admin", line 5, in <module>
    management.execute_from_command_line()

--------------------------------------------

  File "/home/gislab/Envs/geonode/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 387, in empty_variable
    raise self.error(token, "Empty variable tag")
django.template.base.TemplateSyntaxError: Empty variable tag
```

Comment: what is your django version

Comment: My Django version is 1.8.18

Comment: According to the `requirements.txt` inside `2.8.x.zip`, the required Django version is 1.8.19. Can you upgrade Django to 1.8.19?